# How to loop and iterate over Javascript objects containing objetcs and swap values

Tags: javascript, object

```
var person = {
          course1:{Name:"xxx", day:"mon", time:"2am-6pm"},
          course2:{Name:"yyy", day:"tue", time:"7am-9pm"},
          course3:{Name:"zzz", day:"tue", time:"2am-6pm"},
          course4:{Name:"aaa", day:"wed", time:"2am-6pm"},
          course5:{Name:"bbb", day:"thu", time:"2am-6pm"},
          course6:{Name:"ccc", day:"mon", time:"2am-6pm"} 
        };
```

Can anyone please show how to loop and iterate through this person object and swap the course1 and course2 object values(name, day, time) and do something, replace it and swap course1 and course3 again do something and so on...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what is it that you want to achieve at the end of the process? What have you tried so far?

Comment: This really should be an array if you want to access courses by index.

Comment: are you wanting to sort the courses?

Comment: What do you mean by "do something" and by "and so on"? Do you just want to rotate them?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forin.asp

Comment: I want to swap each course values with the other and call a function which returns cost. Want to find which swap yields low cost and keep that swap.

Comment: do you mean "compare", not "swap"? Perhaps you're trying to say "find the course with the lowest cost?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` in order to get all an array of keys, and then you can iterate over it.

Something like that:

```js
const person = {
  course1: {
    Name: "xxx",
    day: "mon",
    time: "2am-6pm"
  },
  course2: {
    Name: "yyy",
    day: "tue",
    time: "7am-9pm"
  },
  course3: {
    Name: "zzz",
    day: "tue",
    time: "2am-6pm"
  },
  course4: {
    Name: "aaa",
    day: "wed",
    time: "2am-6pm"
  },
  course5: {
    Name: "bbb",
    day: "thu",
    time: "2am-6pm"
  },
  course6: {
    Name: "ccc",
    day: "mon",
    time: "2am-6pm"
  }
};

Object.keys(person).forEach((key) => {
  const course = person[key];
  // Do your logic here...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const person = {
    course1:{Name:"xxx", day:"mon", time:"2am-6pm"},
    course2:{Name:"yyy", day:"tue", time:"7am-9pm"},
    course3:{Name:"zzz", day:"tue", time:"2am-6pm"},
    course4:{Name:"aaa", day:"wed", time:"2am-6pm"},
    course5:{Name:"bbb", day:"thu", time:"2am-6pm"},
    course6:{Name:"ccc", day:"mon", time:"2am-6pm"} 
};

const courses = Object.keys(person).filter(course => course !== 'course1');

courses.forEach(key => {
    const copyOne = Object.assign({}, person['course1']);
    const copyCurrent = Object.assign({}, person[key]);

    person['course1'] = copyCurrent;
    person[key] = copyOne;
});

console.log(person);
```

You want to compare with `course1` on each iteration, so it doesn't make sense to use the key in `forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

```
// find the least expensive course

// for easier coding, set a cost property for each course.
for(let course in person) {
    course['cost'] = getCourseCost(course);
}

let lowestCostCourse = person['course1'];

// this compares person['course1'] to itself, but so what
for(let course in person) {
    if(course['cost'] < lowestCostCourse['cost']) {
       lowestCostCourse = course;
    }
}
```